# Ubuntu upgrade to 11.04 from 10.10 no options

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, ubuntu-netbook

I have upgraded ubuntu netbook to 11.04 from 10.10 on my inspiron 1525.
now the screen looks blank (red) once it startup. I can not access much.
only saving thing is that evolution was my default client (after upgrade it asked me whether you want to keep it as ur default mail client).  so using the evolution mail client, evolution starts immediately after I start the computer. i can read my mails (with ethernet connection, wireless doesn't seem to work).

I want to do my regular work like run eclipse etc, and now I ca not do much other than checking mails.

Comment: What type of graphics card do you have? What type of wifi adapter do you have?

Comment: I think he has no shell after logon (nor Unity nor gnome-panels). Switch off auto logon first, then use Ubuntu Classic

Answer (score 0):

For the wireless, remove the broadcom driver source (in synaptic), and install `fireware-b43-installer`.